# How to insert data using XML in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

The whole "inserting multiple records with XML" has pretty much been superseded by table parameters in SQL Server 2008.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Booking].[PlannerQuotation] 
    (@PlannerQuoatetionXML XML,  
     @ResponseXML XML OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @PlannerID INT
    ,@CustomerName NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@MobileNumber NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@ToAddress NVARCHAR(256)
    ,@Subject NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@Message NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@QuotationEmailBody NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@QuotationStatus NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@UserID INT    --Comment : 1
    ,@EntityID INT  --Comment : 1
    ,@ID INT

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        --select details
        SELECT 
            @CustomerName = Plannerxml.nref.value('./CustomerName[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
            ,@PlannerID = Plannerxml.nref.value('./PlannerID[1]', 'INT')    --Comment : 1
            ,@UserID = Plannerxml.nref.value('./UserID[1]', 'INT')  --Comment : 1
            ,@MobileNumber = Plannerxml.nref.value('./MobileNumber[1]', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
            ,@ToAddress = Plannerxml.nref.value('./ToAddress[1]', 'NVARCHAR(256)')
            ,@Subject = Plannerxml.nref.value('(./Subject[1])',  'VARCHAR(100)')
            ,@Message = Plannerxml.nref.value('./Message[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
            ,@QuotationEmailBody = Plannerxml.nref.value('(./QuotationEmailBody[1])', 'VARCHAR(100)')
            ,@QuotationStatus = Plannerxml.nref.value('./QuotationStatus[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
            --,@IsSystemPlan = Plannerxml.nref.value('./IsSystemPlan[1]',  'TINYINT')
            --,@ExpireDate = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Plannerxml.nref.value('(./ExpireDate[1])', 'varchar(22)'), 'T', ' '), 'TZ', ' ') AS DATETIME)
            --,@StartDate = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Plannerxml.nref.value('(./StartDate[1])', 'varchar(22)'), 'T', ' '), 'TZ', ' ') AS DATETIME)
            -- Mode of Operation will contain 3 Options - Copy,Move,Rename
        FROM 
            @PlannerQuoatetionXML.nodes('//PlannerQuoatetionRQ') AS Plannerxml(nref)
        --select Planner id
        --SELECT @plannerID = tblPlanner.colPlannerID.value('@PlannerID', 'int')
        --FROM @PlannerQuoatetionXML.nodes('PlannerQuoatetionRQ/Planners/Planner') tblPlanner(colPlannerID)

        SELECT 
            @EntityID = P.EntityID 
        FROM  
            Booking.Planner 
        WHERE 
            PlannerID = @PlannerID 
            AND IsActive = 1 
            AND ISNULL(IsDeleted, 0) = 0

        -- If Operation is Copy and new planner
        -- create new planner
        IF (UPPER(@ModeofOperation) = 'COPY'AND Isnull(@CopytoPlannerID, 0) = 0)
        BEGIN
            -- Insert New planner name into Planner table
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM Booking.Planner
                           WHERE PlannerName = @PlannerName
                             AND EntityID = @EntityID
                             AND IsActive = 1
                             AND ISNULL(IsDeleted, 0) = 0)
            BEGIN
                --insert into planner
                INSERT INTO Booking.PlannerQuotation (PlannerID, CustomerName,
                                                      MobileNumber, ToAddress,
                                                      Subject, Message,
                                                      QuotationEmailBody,
                                                      QuotationStatus,
                                                      IsActive,
                                                      CreatedBy, CreatedDate)
               VALUES (@PlannerID, @CustomerName,
                       @MobileNumber, @ToAddress, @Subject, @Message,
                       @QuotationEmailBody, @QuotationStatus, 1,
                       @UserID, [Entity].[GetEntityDateTime](@EntityID))

               SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
           END
           ELSE
           BEGIN
               EXEC Logging.HandleError 60208, 'en-US'
           END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ID = @PlannerID
        END
        SET @ResponseXML = '<Response><PlannerQuotationID>'+ CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'</PlannerQuotationID></Response>'
        --end update planner and details record
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
        IF (ERROR_NUMBER() < 60000)
        BEGIN
        EXEC Logging.InsertFailedTransactionLog 'PlannerQuotationInsert'
        ,@PlannerQuotationXML
        END
        EXEC Logging.InsertLogError
    END CATCH
END
```

I use SQL Server 2008 in my web application back end. Apparently I iterate through all the records from the C# code whenever there is a multiple insertion scenario. I have never tried the multiple insert using XML. And I think after reading many blogs about XML manipulation using SQL Server 2008 the process is pretty tedious ..

So my question is: is inserting via XML more efficient than the traditional inserts?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what it is you're really asking. AFAICT you cannot insert like the SQL `INSERT` statement using XML in SQL Server.

Comment: This is - probably - clear for you, but not for a person knowing just the little information you provide... Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide sample data (many records = 2, max three... the rest is the same). Show the target table(s) and expected output.